# How exactly works this AngularJS factory example? Some doubts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, javascript-framework, angularjs-factory

I am absolutly new in AngularJS and I am studying it on a tutorial. I have a doubt related the use of the **factory** in Angular.

I know that a factory is a pattern used to create objects on request.

So in the example there is the following code:

```
// Creates values or objects on demand
angular.module("myApp")     // Get the "myApp" module created into the root.js file (into this module is injected the "serviceModule" service
.value("testValue", "AngularJS Udemy")

// Define a factory named "courseFactory" in which is injected the testValue
.factory("courseFactory", function(testValue) {
    // The factory create a "courseFactory" JSON object;
    var courseFactory = {
            'courseName': testValue,    // Injected value
            'author': 'Tuna Tore',
             getCourse: function(){     // A function is a valid field of a JSON object
             alert('Course: ' + this.courseName);   // Also the call of another function
            }
          };    
    return courseFactory;       // Return the created JSON object
})

// Controller named "factoryController" in which is injected the $scope service and the "courseFactory" factory:
.controller("factoryController", function($scope, courseFactory) {
    alert(courseFactory.courseName);        // When the view is shown first show a popupr retrieving the courseName form the factory
    $scope.courseName = courseFactory.courseName;
    console.log(courseFactory.courseName);
    courseFactory.getCourse();  // Cause the second alert message
});
```

And this is the code, associated to this **factoryController** controller,  inside the HTML page:

```
<div  ng-controller="factoryController"> 
    {{ courseName }} 
</div>
```

So it is pretty clear for me that:

- The **factoryController** use the **courseFactory** factory because is is injected
- The first thing that happen when I open the page is that an alert mesage is shown because it is called the:

  ```
  alert(courseFactory.courseName);
  ```
- Then put into the **$scope.courseName** property (inside the **$scope object) the value of the **courseName** field of the **courseFactory** JSON object).

And here my first doubt. I have that the factory is defined by:

```
.factory("courseFactory", function(testValue)
```

that I think it means (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) that my factory is named **courseFactory** and basically is a function that retutn the **courseFactory** JSON object.

So this is creating me some confusion (I came from Java) because in Java I call a factory class and I obtain an instance of an object created by the factory. But in this case it seems to me that doing:

```
$scope.courseName = courseFactory.courseName;
```

it seems to me that the **courseName** is retrieved directly by the **courseFactory** JSON object and I am not using the **courseFactory**.

How it exactly works? Why I am not calling some getter on the factory? (or something like this)

Comment: I'd recommend to read up on answers of this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify things There are two known methods to create functions ( and methods ) that are Usable among all states ( consider it as creating a function in global scope ) , these are factory and service.

you may want to read this first **[Factory vs Service](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html)**

> it seems to me that the courseName is retrieved directly by the
>   courseFactory JSON object and I am not using the courseFactory.

Actually this is partially true , as Angular use DI concept ( depency injection ) , you will have to inject your factory ( which by default returns an object , and corresponding functions as attributes ) , case you don't ; you will not be able to use your factory object methods.

Angular is not magic , it is just most people don't realize the most basic concepts of JavaScript , specially Developers coming from different programming environment such as C# , C++ , or Java

Comment: Infact I am here for this reason...because I am used to reasoning in pure OO paradigm...I alwais used JavaScript\JQuery inside webapp in simple way and now for the first time I am studying deeply the JavaScript paradigm

Comment: I would recommend you read a book called JavaScript Succinctly by Cody Lindley , which will make your trip with JavaScript much more fun , and easy .. good luck :).

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

When you return the courseFactory object in the factory statement, the injected courseFactory in the controller becomes THAT object. Therefore, when you do `$scope.courseName = courseFactory.courseName;` in the controller, you are actually referencing to the returned object that is injected into the controller as `courseFactory`. So you don't need a getter, because the courseFactory in your controller is already the object. You can do a `console.log(courseFactory);` in your controller to see what the courseFactory is. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> When an Angular application starts with a given application module,
>   Angular creates a new instance of injector, which in turn creates a
>   registry of recipes as a union of all recipes defined in the core "ng"
>   module, application module and its dependencies. The injector then
>   consults the recipe registry when it needs to create an object for
>   your application.

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 1):

Factory is a Singleton service.  When you inject the factory in the controller or in any other factory,  u get the exact json object which u have defined.  It will not create any new instance every time you call it. Factory is initialized only once